# iOS Swift round views inside cell show incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, rounding, uicollectionviewcell

Evening, I have a calendar collection.
The cells have some rounded views shown incorrectly at the first time, but when they are reloaded they are shown correctly.

I know that the issue is that at the first time the cell doesn't know the right size of the frame.

What I've tried:

1- call the round function inside `layoutSubviews()`: only the right side is rounded correctly

2 - call the round function inside the `cellWillLayout`: nothing changes

This is the rounding function:

```
func makeRound() {
        print("rounding")
        currentDayView.layer.cornerRadius = currentDayView.frame.height/2
        currentDayView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        currentDayView.clipsToBounds = true

        selectedDayView.layer.cornerRadius = selectedDayView.frame.height/2
        selectedDayView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        selectedDayView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: `layoutSubviews` is usually the correct place. What class' `layoutSubviews` did you put it in? Do you have any transforms on your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to do corner rounding is either in each view's `layoutSubviews` or (for example, if you haven't sub-classed them) put it in your view controllers `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Each view in your case is the `layoutSubviews` of `currentDayView` and `selectedDayView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `layoutSubviews` method, then call your method inside it:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
        self.makeRound()
}
```